# Do US companies have citizenship requirements for security-related employees?

Tags: corporate-policy, career

Do U.S. based companies or corporations generally have policies restricting their security staff to certain nationalities or are they generally open to all qualified persons regardless of citizenship?

Comment: This isn't an Info Sec question. This is a US immigration question. As for company-specific policies, some companies require security clearance that can only be granted to citizens (regardless of the nation involved).

Comment: Why would this question be consdered as off topic?
For me this is clearly within the security policy and more accurately within the chapter human ressources, conditions to access to priviledged admin positions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only situation where such a citizenship requirement would typically apply was if the SE position was with a Federal Government contractor, and the position required a USG security clearance. Since those are granted to US citizens, a non-US citizen would be ineligible for it.

That being said, in the private sector, I know of no such requirement, other than to say that if one requires a US work visa, some companies may not have the ability or desire to sponsor a candidate for one, and would not respond to the application.

Comment: If I am not mistaking, security clearance for some positions (both government and private sector) requires you to also have at least X number of years working/living in the country.

Comment: Not necessarily a requirement, but in the background investigation they will ask for details of all your foreign travels and residencies. Depending on the clearance level it can get pretty in-depth.

Comment: There are Federal contracts that do not require a security clearance, but *do* require citizenship of those working on the contract.  (I tripped over this one when we had a Federal contract and a Canadian staff member.)